# Magento 2 | Get product info from mysql query

Tags: magento2, database

I'm currently working on a Backend-like Page for special Customers within our shop. Theese special customers should be able to export product-data for a predefinied Shopsystem and other internal (shop related) stuff.

I was able to create a query with a thousands `while` statements but it looks pretty bad and is hard to understand / edit for someone with no understanding.

I road about `MYSQL inner join` statements and stuff like that but got never into it.

Has anyone a `query` to get the following data?

- Product Name
- Product SKU
- Product Price
- Short-description
- Description
- Main & Thumbnail image
- Additional images
- Product Categories

Or could explain / link ressources to get to a result like this ?

---

**EDIT - 08/09/2017**

I road a few documentaions and learned some new stuff. My query currently looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    catalog_product_entity.entity_id AS id,
    catalog_product_entity.type_id AS type,
    catalog_product_entity.attribute_set_id AS attribute_id, 
    catalog_product_entity.sku AS sku, 
    catalog_product_entity_varchar.value AS name,
    catalog_product_entity_decimal.value AS price
FROM catalog_product_entity
    LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar ON catalog_product_entity.entity_id = catalog_product_entity_varchar.entity_id
    LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal ON catalog_product_entity.entity_id = catalog_product_entity_decimal.entity_id
WHERE 
    catalog_product_entity_varchar.attribute_id = "71" AND 
    catalog_product_entity_varchar.store_id = "0" AND
    catalog_product_entity_decimal.attribute_id = "75";
```

So far so good, everything works like i want it to be. The only part I dont understand ist the part where i have to select a new entry from `catalog_product_entity_varchar` to get the description and other attributes

Anything i can read about that ? Anyone who can help ?

Comment: For every attribute you need to add a join based on its id to get it so if you want to get 5 (non static) attributes you need **at least** 5 joins. See my answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, it is not that simple, Magento database modeling is in eav (entity,attribute,value) so it requires a lot of **JOINS**

I **recommand** doing this by passing through **Magento collections** (in php script)

But anyway here is the **MySQL** query that responds to your need :

```sql
SELECT e.entity_id AS 'id',
       v1.value AS 'name',
       e.sku,
       d1.value AS 'price',
       t1.value AS 'short_description',
       t2.value AS 'description',
       v2.value AS 'image',
       v3.value AS 'thumbnail',
       mg.value AS 'media_gallery',
       cids.category_ids AS 'category_ids',
       cids.category_names AS 'category_names'
FROM catalog_product_entity e
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar v1 ON e.entity_id = v1.entity_id
AND v1.store_id = 0
AND v1.attribute_id =
  (SELECT attribute_id
   FROM eav_attribute
   WHERE attribute_code = 'name'
     AND entity_type_id =
       (SELECT entity_type_id
        FROM eav_entity_type
        WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_text t1 ON e.entity_id = t1.entity_id
AND t1.store_id = 0
AND t1.attribute_id =
  (SELECT attribute_id
   FROM eav_attribute
   WHERE attribute_code = 'short_description'
     AND entity_type_id =
       (SELECT entity_type_id
        FROM eav_entity_type
        WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_text t2 ON e.entity_id = t2.entity_id
AND t2.store_id = 0
AND t2.attribute_id =
  (SELECT attribute_id
   FROM eav_attribute
   WHERE attribute_code = 'description'
     AND entity_type_id =
       (SELECT entity_type_id
        FROM eav_entity_type
        WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar v2 ON e.entity_id = v2.entity_id
AND v2.store_id = 0
AND v2.attribute_id =
  (SELECT attribute_id
   FROM eav_attribute
   WHERE attribute_code = 'image'
     AND entity_type_id =
       (SELECT entity_type_id
        FROM eav_entity_type
        WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar v3 ON e.entity_id = v3.entity_id
AND v3.store_id = 0
AND v3.attribute_id =
  (SELECT attribute_id
   FROM eav_attribute
   WHERE attribute_code = 'thumbnail'
     AND entity_type_id =
       (SELECT entity_type_id
        FROM eav_entity_type
        WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_decimal d1 ON e.entity_id = d1.entity_id
AND d1.store_id = 0
AND d1.attribute_id =
  (SELECT attribute_id
   FROM eav_attribute
   WHERE attribute_code = 'price'
     AND entity_type_id =
       (SELECT entity_type_id
        FROM eav_entity_type
        WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT m1.entity_id,
          GROUP_CONCAT(m2.value) AS value
   FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity m1
   INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_media_gallery m2 ON m2.value_id = m1.value_id
   AND m2.attribute_id =
     (SELECT attribute_id
      FROM eav_attribute
      WHERE attribute_code = 'media_gallery'
        AND entity_type_id =
          (SELECT entity_type_id
           FROM eav_entity_type
           WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
   GROUP BY m1.entity_id) mg ON e.entity_id = mg.entity_id
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT product_id,
          GROUP_CONCAT(c.category_id SEPARATOR ',') AS category_ids,
          GROUP_CONCAT(cv.value SEPARATOR ',') AS category_names
   FROM catalog_category_product c
   INNER JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar cv ON c.category_id = cv.entity_id
   AND cv.store_id = 0
   AND cv.attribute_id =
     (SELECT attribute_id
      FROM eav_attribute
      WHERE attribute_code = 'name'
        AND entity_type_id =
          (SELECT entity_type_id
           FROM eav_entity_type
           WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_category'))
   GROUP BY product_id) cids ON e.entity_id = cids.product_id ;
```

Try it and let me know if it helped you.

**Note** : If you are using Magento Enterprise Edition (Adobe Commerce), then the joins need to be updated with `row_id` instead of `entity_id`

Comment: I definitly have to learn more SQL. It worked like a charm and i was able to add a few things that i missed on my question. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it helped you,  you are welcome

Comment: Showing as sql error

Comment: @jafar pinjar The query has no error, please check that your running it on *Magento2* database and not Magento1

Answer (score 0):

try this one, it worked faster. Note that you might have to change the attribute ids by looking them in `eav_attribute` table. Feel free to change `where clause` conditions as per your need.

```
select cpe.entity_id,
 cpe.sku,
 cpev.value as name,
    cpr.`parent_id`,
   cpe1.sku as parent_sku,
  cpet1.value as short_description, 
  cpev2.value as url_key, 
  cpev3.value as brand,
   cpei.value as status,
   cpei1.value as visibility,
   (select class_name from tax_class where class_id = cpei2.value and class_type='PRODUCT') as tax_class, 
   (select value from eav_attribute_option_value eaov where option_id=cpei3.value and store_id=0) as include_in_feed,
   cped.value as price,
   cped1.value as special_price,
   mg.value as media_gallery,
   cids.category_ids,
   cids.category_names,
   cids.category_paths
   from catalog_product_entity cpe 
left join catalog_product_entity_varchar as cpev on cpev.entity_id=cpe.entity_id and cpev.attribute_id=73 -- name --
left join catalog_product_entity_text as cpet1 on cpet1.entity_id=cpe.entity_id and cpet1.attribute_id=76 -- short description --
left join catalog_product_entity_varchar as cpev2 on cpev2.entity_id=cpe.entity_id and cpev2.attribute_id=119 -- url key --
left join catalog_product_entity_varchar as cpev3 on cpev3.entity_id=cpe.entity_id and cpev3.attribute_id=136 -- brand --
left join catalog_product_entity_int as cpei on cpei.entity_id=cpe.entity_id and cpei.attribute_id=97 -- status --
left join catalog_product_entity_int as cpei1 on cpei1.entity_id=cpe.entity_id and cpei1.attribute_id=99 -- visibility --
left join catalog_product_entity_int as cpei2 on cpei2.entity_id=cpe.entity_id and cpei2.attribute_id=134 -- tax class --
left join catalog_product_entity_int as cpei3 on cpei3.entity_id=cpe.entity_id and cpei3.attribute_id=184 -- include in feed --
left join catalog_product_entity_decimal as cped on cped.entity_id=cpe.entity_id and cped.attribute_id=77 -- price --
left join catalog_product_entity_decimal as cped1 on cped1.entity_id=cpe.entity_id and cped1.attribute_id=78 -- specials price --
left join catalog_product_relation cpr on cpr.child_id=cpe.entity_id left join catalog_product_entity cpe1 on cpe1.entity_id=cpr.parent_id
left join cataloginventory_stock_status css on cpe.entity_id=css.product_id 
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT product_id,
          GROUP_CONCAT(distinct c.category_id SEPARATOR ',') AS category_ids,
          GROUP_CONCAT(distinct cv.value  SEPARATOR ',') AS category_names,
          GROUP_CONCAT(distinct cv1.value SEPARATOR ',') AS category_paths
   FROM catalog_category_product c
   INNER JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar cv ON c.category_id = cv.entity_id and cv.attribute_id=45 and cv.store_id=0
   INNER JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar cv1 ON c.category_id = cv1.entity_id and cv1.attribute_id=118 and cv.store_id=0
   GROUP BY product_id) cids ON cpe.entity_id = cids.product_id
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT m1.entity_id,
          GROUP_CONCAT(m2.value) AS value
   FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity m1
   INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_media_gallery m2 ON m2.value_id = m1.value_id and m2.`attribute_id`=90
   GROUP BY m1.entity_id) mg ON cpe.entity_id=mg.entity_id
where cpe.type_id='simple' and css.stock_status=1 and css.qty>0 limit 1000 offset 10;
```